# Do `fgetc`, `fputc`, `fgets` and `fputs` require a file opened in text mode, and `fread` and `fwrite` require a file in binary mode?

Tags: c, io

When using `fgetc`, `fputc`, `fgets` and `fputs` for a file, do I need to ensure that I have `open`ed the file in text mode not binary mode?

When using `fread` and `fwrite`, do I need to  `open`ed the file in binary mode not text mode?

In Linux, I guess there is no difference. But what if in Windows which I currently have no access to?

Comment: Short answer: "textmode" is an artifact, created by Microsoft.

Comment: @wildplasser Did not MACs (bitd) encode end-of-line as `'\r'`?  "Text mode" was not a MS monopoly.  Even today, with `"Text mode", one may see a byte-order-mark.

Comment: Warning, I edited my answer after some tries, under WIndows the text mode also concern `fputc/fgetc/../_read/_write`, so all r/w function rather than only _fread_ and _fwrite_, and that even the documentation of Microsoft forget to speak about that for _fgetc_ / _fputc_ etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[edit after a try under windows using *mingw*]

The difference between text and binary mode only exist under Windows and not only concern *fwrite* and *fread* but also *fgetc*/*fputc*/.../`_read`/`_write`

On text mode if a file contains the sequence \r\n only the \n is get when you read like if the file does not contain the \r. In binary mode the two characters are return. Note [fread Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fread?view=vs-2019) and [_read Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/read?view=vs-2019) speak about that case but unfortunately nothing is said for *fgetc* in [fget fgetwc Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fgetc-fgetwc?view=vs-2019)

When writing if the stream is opened in text mode each \n is written as a \r\n pair. Note the replacement has no effect on the size return by *fwrite*. In binary mode \n is written unchanged, there is no \r added. Note [fwrite Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fwrite?view=vs-2019) and [_write Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/write?view=vs-2019) speak about that case but unfortunately nothing is said for *fputc* in [fputc fputwc Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fputc-fputwc?view=vs-2019)

Fortunately in text mode under Windows read and write functions are symmetric, when you write in text mode foo\nbar then you read the produced file still in text mode you get foo\nbar, but there is foo\r\nbar into the file.

So

> When using fgetc, fputc, fgets and fputs for a file, do I need to ensure that I have opened the file in text mode not binary mode?

the mode has an impact

> When using fread and fwrite, do I need to  opened the file in binary mode not text mode?

Like for the other functions it is your choice, but if the file is also read/write by an other tool it is may be better to open in text mode in case these tools expect a \r before a \n when reading or producing the pair when writing. Of course you can also open in binary mode and explicitly write a \r before a \n by yourself.

If the file is only for you using C to read/write it may be better to always open in binary mode to have in the file only what you explicitly ask for to have. This is enforced if you use *ftell*/*fseek*.

As said in [ftell Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/ftell-ftelli64?view=vs-2019) ftell and _ftelli64 may not reflect the physical byte offset for streams opened in text mode, because text mode causes carriage return-linefeed translation.

It is worst concerning *fseek*, as said in [fseek Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fseek-fseeki64?view=vs-2019) :

> for streams opened in text mode, fseek and _fseeki64 have limited use, because carriage return-linefeed translations can cause fseek and _fseeki64 to produce unexpected results. The only fseek and _fseeki64 operations guaranteed to work on streams opened in text mode are:
>
> - Seeking with an offset of 0 relative to any of the origin values.
> - Seeking from the beginning of the file with an offset value returned from a call to ftell when using fseek or _ftelli64 when using _fseeki64.

Comment: **All** input output functions are impacted by the textmode vs binary mode setting under Windows and similar legacy systems: `fgetc()` will return `'\n'` if the stream contains `\r\n` and `fputc('\n')` will indeed write 2 bytes to the output stream, `'\n'` being converted to `\r\n`.

Comment: @chqrlie hello, there is nothing about that in the Microsoft Docs

Comment: The translation occurs upon flushing the stream's buffer to the actual file and filling the buffer from the input file. It does not matter which function is used to read or write the stream. As a matter of fact, the lower level Posix compatible I/O functions perform this translation when the file is opened with `O_TEXT` and not when the file is opened with `O_BINARY`.

Comment: @chqrlie in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fgetc-fgetwc?view=vs-2019 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fputc-fputwc?view=vs-2019 the mode only concern _fputwc_ and _fgetwc_, *not* _fgetc_ and _fputc_

Comment: The doc in reference is confusing and the example is nefarious: `ch = fgetc( stream ); for( i=0; (i < 80 ) && ( feof( stream ) == 0 ); i++ ) { buffer[i] = (char)ch; ch = fgetc( stream ); }`. Microsoft documents the behavior of `fgetwc`/`fputwc` on text vs binary streams in a confusing way: `fgetwc()` reads 2 bytes from a binary file and a variable number of bytes from a text file, depending on the actual encoding selected. 2 bytes is hardly Unicode as they pretend...

Comment: They do not say anything about CR/LF translation for `fgetc()`/`fputc()` in corresponding pages, the documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/text-and-binary-mode-file-i-o?view=vs-2019

Comment: @chqrlie yes I see that page first before to find the others

Comment: @chqrlie I will try to do some tests tomorrow, I am too tired right now, but I do not have Microsoft compiler since my very-old PC died, I just have _mingw_. Good night

Comment: Microsoft still documents the ancient ^Z hack inherited from CP/M where file sizes dd not have byte precision and obsolete since MS/DOS 2.0... this platform is so quirky...

Comment: @chqrlie I just did a test with mingw under Windows and you are right, whatever the used function in text mode writing a \n put \r\n in the file and the reverse when reading

Comment: @chqrlie Ofc I edited my answer, I also added some words about _ftell_ / _fseek_. _Quirky_ is a (very / too) gentle word considering the behavior ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Did you experiment and come to the conclusing using Microsoft's implementation of the standard C library? How about GNU Libc in Windows?

Comment: How about fprintf() and fscanf() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56339340/does-fprintf-and-fscanf-in-windows-require-a-file-to-be-opened-in-text-m

Answer (score 1):

No. **All** stdio input and output functions are defined in terms of repeated calls to `fgetc` or `fputc`. Aside from POSIX requirements on top (mainly locking being for the whole larger operation rather than at the individual `fgetc`/`fputc` granularity), there is no difference between calling `fputc` or `fgetc` in a loop yourself, or doing the equivalent with `fwrite` or `fread`.

If the C implementation you use treats text files differently from binary, that treatment applies no matter which functions you use to perform the operations.

Comment: Thanks. "All stdio input and output functions are defined in terms of repeated calls to fgetc or fputc". Are `fwrite` and `fread` implemented  "in terms of repeated calls to fgetc or fputc"?

Comment: That's how they're *defined* by the language. They xan be implemented any way the implementor wants as long as they behave as if by repeated calls, so of course most implementors will do something to make them faster.