# Does `fprintf()` and `fscanf()` in Windows require a file to be opened in text mode

Tags: c, windows, io

When using `fprintf()` and `fscanf()` on text files in Windows, is it necessary or recommended to open the file in text mode compared to binary mode?

Does the answer depend on using Microsoft's implementation of the standard C library or GNU Libc in Windows?

Comment: it doesn't matter, except that in binary mode `\r` isn't added (no end of line conversion). Depends on what you want

Comment: Thanks. can you elaborate "depends on what you want"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When using fprintf() and fscanf() on text files in Windows, is it necessary or recommended to open the file in text mode compared to binary mode?

*fprintf* / *fscanf* are based on low level function *fputc* / *fgetc* etc so the management of the mode text/binary follow the same rules we see in [Do `fgetc`, `fputc`, `fgets` and `fputs` require a file opened in text mode, and `fread` and `fwrite` require a file in binary mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56331955/do-fgetc-fputc-fgets-and-fputs-require-a-file-opened-in-text-mode-and)

> Does the answer depend on using Microsoft's implementation of the standard C library or GNU Libc in Windows?

The *mingw* libc are supported my the Microsoft libs, the behavior is the one of the Microsoft libc, some function follow ISO but not GNU / gcc which is an implementation, not a standard. Note generally Microsoft is not fully conformant to any specific POSIX standard (see [Compatibility in Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/compatibility?view=vs-2019) )

Answer (score 2):

In windows, binary or text mode differ by end of line conversion.

The *system* does the end-of-line conversion (through low-level POSIX `write` and `read` for instance). But it doesn't matter: end of line conversion is performed in text mode, and nothing is changed in binary mode.

The `printf` and other formatting functions end up calling a low-level read/write/whatever function that handles this end-of-line conversion.

- When you write a newline character `\n` in a file opened in text mode, the system adds an `\r` character before the newline.
- When you read `\n` in a file opened in text mode, the system removes the `\r` character which is before the newline. If there isn't, it doesn't remove anything. If there are 2 `\r` characters, it only removes one.

Note that writing text files in binary mode can be useful if you want to write Linux-compliant text files, without `\r` character.